# Fastest way to copy sign value among 68k data registers. (Branchless conditional negation of an integer)

Tags: assembly, optimization, bit-manipulation, signed, 68000

I'm looking for an optimized way to change the sign of a value contained in a Data Register using the sign from a value in another Data Register.

Source register will contain either 1 or -1 and destination be always positive therefore all is needed is multiplication. Here's some pseudo code of what I'd do:

```
MOVE.B #-1,D0
MOVE.W #173,D1
MULS.W D0,D1
```

After that simple math D1 would carry the sign from D0 and become either -173 or 173. Which is the desired result but MULS takes up to 70 cycles and I'm hoping to save some by finding a trick to somehow only "copy" the sign .

Last word: trick should be branchless as branching is what I'm trying to prevent by copying the sign in the first place.

Thanks in advance for any information or advice.

Comment: First arithmetic shift right to get 0 or -1, then xor followed by adding the lsb should do the trick. `D0 >>= 1; D1 = (D1 ^ D0) + (D0 & 1)`.

Comment: @Jester: Subtract `0` or `-1` so you can skip the AND.  Like in the absolute-value idiom where you materialize a `0` or `-1` with `a >> 31` and then XOR/SUB with it to conditionally negate, like you're doing here.

Comment: To understand the above, remember that `-x == ~x + 1`, and `~x == x ^ -1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah that's better thanks

Comment: Note that to use your strawman (with MULS) or the one provided by @Peter, you'll need a word-sized 1 or -1 in `D0.W` to start with instead of byte-sized only in `D0.B` , so either use `MOVEQ #-1, D0`, (best/shortest) or `MOVE.W #-1, D0`, or a `MOVE.B/EXT.W` pair (also then use word sized operations for shifts, XOR, SUB).

Comment: @ErikEidt: good point, took that into account when finishing my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could branchlessly select between `x` and `-x`, using a bit-hack.

But you can do better: 2's complement negation can be expressed as `-x == ~x + 1`, and both the NOT and increment can be expressed in terms of XOR and SUB with `-1`.  But the same operations with a `0` are no-ops, leaving the value unchanged.

(This trick is often used for 2's complement absolute value, where the 0 or -1 is obtained from arithmetic right shift, `x >> 31`, to copy the sign bit to all bits of a register.  i.e. applying your conditional-sign-flip operation to the same number that gave us the sign bit.  [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs))

Of course, you need a WORD sized `-1`, not just BYTE, since you need to cover all bits of value you're negating (or not); as Erik points out, this means `move.w  #-1, d0` or `ext.w` if you can't promote your byte value to a word at the origin.

```
;; d0 = word  1 or -1
   asr.w     #1, d0
;; d0 = word  0 or -1

   eor.w     d0, d1           ;  ~d1 
   sub.w     d0, d1           ;  ~d1 - 1  (or unchanged for d0=0)

; d1 = d1 or -d1  according to d0
```

---

**If you want to negate based on the sign of some other number**, generate a `0` / `-1` directly instead of ever creating a `1` / `-1`.
(i.e. an integer `copysign`, a bit like multiplying by `signum(y)` if ISO C had a `signum` function, but without zeroing on `y=0`.)

Normally you'd use `x >> 15` with an arithmetic right shift, but M68K immediate shifts only allow a count from 1..8.  (And are slow for large counts on CPUs without a barrel shifter).  So you'd actually want get 16 copies of the sign bit by sign-extending to 32-bit and then swapping halves to put it in place:

```
;; manufacture a 0 / -1 word according to d0.w < 0
   ext.l   d0       ; high 16 bits = 0 / -1
   swap    d0       ; those are now the low bits

; optionally: ext.l  d0   ; to make a 32-bit 0 / -1
```

For a 32-bit source, you might `tst.l d0,d0` / `smi d0` (Set if MInus) to produce a byte-sized 0 / -1, then sign-extend that.  (Although only 68020 can do that in one `extb.l` instruction; 68000 would need `ext.w` + `ext.l`)

---

Or **if you have a MC68020 or later CPU**, you can use a sign-extending bit-field extract of just the sign bit.  `bfexts d0 {15:1}, d0`.  It's a 4-byte instruction, so same code-size as ext.l + swap, but it extends to 32-bit and could work on a 32-bit source register without additional instructions.  And even for 16-bit integers, it's a single instruction instead of 2, so it may be good, especially if it's executing from cache?  Or not since it seems to be slower.

Other alternatives:

- `moveq #15` into a register for an `asr` by 15 or 31.  Slower even on m68k than ext/swap.
- rotate left by 1, `and`-immediate with 1 to isolate the sign bit as a 0 / 1, and `neg`.  Works easily for 32-bit inputs, maybe good there especially on 68000 where a shift by 31 might be slow.  But `rol` is slowish on 68020.

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC68020UM.pdf includes instruction timings for a 68020, as "best case" (overlap with execution of previous instruction, and hot in cache), "cached case" (just cache, no overlap), and "worst case" (neither)

- `bfexts Dn` : 5 cycles (best) / 8 (cached) / 8 (worst)
- `EXT Dn` : 1 (best) / 4 (cached) / 4 (worst)
- `SWAP Rx,Ry` : 1 (best) / 4 (cached) / 4 (worst)

So maybe `bfexts` isn't a good choice for 16-bit inputs, when ext/swap would do the job.

- `ASR Dn`: 3 (best) / 6 (cached) / 6 (worst).  Interestingly, immediate-count logical shifts are faster than this, but arithmetic shifts are the same.  (68020 apparently has a barrel shifter; performance doesn't depend on the count. 68000 may not, IDK.)
- `MOVEQ #<data>, Dn`: 0 (best) / 2 (cached) / 3 (worst)
- `ROL Dn`: 5 (best) / 8 (cached) / 8 (worst)
- `ANDI #<data>,Dn`: 0 (best) / 2 (cached) / 3 (worst)
- `EOR Dn,Dn`: 0 (best) / 2 (cached) / 3 (worst)
- `SUB EA,Dn`: 0 (best) / 2 (cached) / 3 (worst).  Fetch EA time for a Dn source is 0 cycles.

Overlap (creating the best case) depends on how slow the previous instruction was, I think, especially memory access rather than core cycles; the manual I linked has some details, but they also make a big point that you can't just add up best or worst cases except as lower/upper bounds; you need to benchmark to find typical run times.  IDK how data-dependencies affect this.

These are 68020 timings, since we had a choice there of `bfexts` vs. `ext`/`swap`.  On 68000, ext/swap is almost certainly better than any alternative.

Comment: N.B. `asr.w #15,d0` is not possible -- you could do `moveq #15,d1; asr.w d1,d0`, but I guess `tst.w d0; smi d0; ext.w d0` is faster (I did not actually look it up, but I remember shifting takes longer depending on the shift-amount on 68000).

Comment: @chtz: Hrm, doesn't m68k have an instruction to swap 32-bit halves?  Maybe sign-extend to 32-bit with one instruction, then swap the 0 / -1 high half to the bottom?  (Like x86 `cdq`, except not actually a separate register.)  Unfortunately Godbolt didn't have an m68k C compiler, and it's not one of the standard targets for LLVM, or I would have asked a compiler.  Maybe I'll grab one of my dad's 68000 assembly books from my bookshefl...  Ah I see, `asr` only has a 3-bit field for an immediate count, biased to allow 1..8 as the count.

Comment: Right! `ext.l d0; swap d0` is very likely faster.

Comment: @chtz: 68020 can use `bfexts d0 {15:1}, d0` or `bfexts d0 {31:1}, d0` to sign-extend the sign bit as a 1-bit field into the full register.  Otherwise yeah, tst/smi / ext/ext might be useful for a 32-bit source, although swap/ext.t/swap/ext.l would also work for 32-bit inputs.  I guess for code-size, a moveq-immediate and asr would be best for a 32-bit value on 68000.  Anyway, thanks for the m68k details, updated that part of my answer to actually work.

Comment: Thanks! it works and now it takes only 16 cycles!

Comment: You are right about choosing -1/0 against -1/1, when I had to choose it I wondered which one would have been the best choice. I picked -1/1 because it had to express a direction and this way its value is ready to be ADD to increment or decrement another value, also it could be inverted just with a NEG.

Comment: @KONEY: Ah, if the -1 / +1 value is actually useful in other parts of your program, then it's a valid trade-off.  -1 / 0 can be flipped just as easily with NOT, though; 1's complement inverse, but you can't just add it to something else to inc or dec so there is still a downside.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm trying the ext/swap thing so instead of ASR.W #1,D3 I used EXT.L D3 + SWAP D3.  I reckon I understood correctly since code works as before but maybe not because I don't see how this could be faster as basically an 8 cycles instruction is replaced by two of 4 cycles. I'm targeting 68000 and using this tool for quick profiling small snippets of code: https://68kcounter-web.vercel.app/

Comment: @KONEY: https://68kcounter-web.vercel.app/ is wrong about instruction size for `ASR.W #1,D3`.  It shows it being a 4-byte instruction, but it's actually only 2.  I didn't look elsewhere for 68000 timing info so IDK if it's right about cycle counts other than memory fetch; are you testing on an actual 68000 (like Atari ST or Mac?), or a cycle-accurate simulator?  If not, then an emulator might happen to decode ext and swap faster than an asr?  Seems unlikely though.

Comment: https://wiki.neogeodev.org/index.php?title=68k_instructions_timings#Shift_and_rotate_instructions confirms that `asr.w #1, Dn` is an 8-cycle instruction; timing is 6 + 2n.  And agrees with ext.l and swap being 4-cycle instructions.  So on a real 68000, performance should be break-even.  Good idea to try it, though.

Comment: Oh, apparently https://68kcounter-web.vercel.app/ shows `ASR.W #1,D3` as a 2-byte instruction if it's not followed by a blank line!  That's a weird bug.  And putting the blank line back, I can't reproduce it. Maybe something about how I copy/pasted from SO?  Anyway, IDK how you're finding that ext/swap is faster than asr.  They should be the same speed, or worse because of code-size.  The section of my answer that talks about using them is for the case where your input is *not* known to be -1 / +1, but instead you want to apply the sign of one arbitrary number to another.  So `asr` by 1 fails.